# How can I prove this series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Wolfram Alpha says the following series converges, but I can't figure out how to prove it.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n)+\sqrt{n}}{n^2+5}$$

Can I use a comparison test with a simple harmonic *p* series, or is there a better way?

Comment: That is quite trivial, my friend: given that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$ is absolutely convergent, your series is absolutely convergent too.

Comment: Thanks for whoever found the duplicate. I must be in the same class as this guy...

Comment: You're welcome!  Just FYI ... You can see the person who marked this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Comparison:
$$
\left|\frac{\sin n + \sqrt n}{n^2+5}\right| \le \frac{2\sqrt n}{n^2} = \frac 2 {n^{3/2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. If a series is *[absolutely convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence)* then it is *convergent*, observe that, for $n\ge1$,
$$
\left|\frac{\sin(n)+\sqrt{n}}{n^2+5} \right|\le\frac{\left|\sin(n)+\sqrt{n}\right|}{n^2+5} \le \frac{\left|2\sqrt{n}\right|}{n^2} =2\frac1{n^{3/2}}.
$$